# HTML/CSS - Font Icons : Class from fontawesome not working when calling it from css file

Tags: html, css, class, icons, font-awesome

I'm pretty "new" to HTML/CSS coding so apologies if this topic is trivial.

This concern the use of font icons, more precisely Fontawesome.

- HTML FILE : In my html document, the icon is embeded that way (within a "menu" class) : `<i class="fas fa-user"></i>`
- CSS FILE : So, in order to apply styles to this icon : `.menu .fas {width: 2rem;}`

But it doesnt work for some reason.

When I inspect the code in my browser, the line from html appear to be not used (grayed out), and instead I have new lines starting with :
`<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-user" ...`

So when I change my css code to : `.menu .svg-inline--fa{width: 2rem;}`
It works.

I would love to have some explanations, thanks ! :)

Comment: You should not change the Font Awesome classes or HTML themselves. Add something around it, with a class you own, to do the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in your Font awesome project and then go to settings. There you can select the technology to use for your font : Web Font (CSS pseudo element) or SVGs.

SVG is using JS to replace element with SVGs.

[image: FontAwesome settings page]

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed I had SVG, selected. I changed to Web Fonts and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how Font Awesome generates icons.

When you use `<i class="fas fa-user"></i>,` FA (Font Awesome) replaces it with an inline SVG element that represents the icon. The element has a class of `svg-inline--fa fa-user,` which is why your CSS targeting `.menu .fas` doesn't work for you.

For FA, you need to target the element directly, which is why `.menu .svg-inline--fa { width: 2rem; }` sets the width of the icon to 2rem.

So in closing, `.svg-inline--fa` being targeted, applies styles to all FA icons in your project, but if you want to style them differently, you can use the icon specific class, such as `.fa-user` in your case.

I recommend you read the Font Awesome Documentation to familiarize yourself with the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for all those details, makes sense, but it's seems kindda wierd how it works. That means I have to check the code in the browser to find the right class to call, which seems not optimal.